# Updating Odoo by apt-get

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, odoo, odoo-9

I did the installation of odoo through .deb: `apt-get install odoo`.
I want to update the package since the latest version is 24-Apr-2019 but when I run `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install odoo` tells me:

> odoo is already the newest version (9.0c.20181022)

.

Is it possible to update in this way odoo? , Thanks for the help

Comment: is this the enterprise version?

Comment: There probably is no newer version for the provided sources. Where do you get the sources? Hopefully from http://nightly.odoo.com/9.0/nightly/deb/. Because there are newer versions as you've already known.

Comment: It's the community version. Yes, I got the .deb from that source but some time ago (2018-10-22) I installed that version but I don't know if it can be updated by apt-get. @CZoellner

Comment: You've just downloaded and installed it manually? Why not using the sources to get `apt-get` to work: http://nightly.odoo.com/

Comment: I used the official installation guide:    # wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add -
# echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/9.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt-get update && apt-get install odoo. The installation was done last year but I want to upgrade to the latest version available.

Comment: Post the question in Askubuntu they might be able to help you with finding a ppa or other sources or do an install from source

Answer (score 1):

First you need to run `apt-get update` this will add the repository of odoo deb package. Then you can run this command `sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install odoo`.